# How do I transfer data from a client-side form input to a server-side Nodejs script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement functionality which takes data from form inputs on the client-side and sends it to the server to be processed by my Nodejs backend.

I've got the server-side function working, but I'm unsure as to how I would go about sending the data from the client-side form to my backend server via the `$.ajax` `GET` request that submits the form.

The code I have so far:

**Server side function:**

```
app.get('/id', function(req,res) {
    var query = "SELECT * FROM Control";
    connection.query(query, function() {
            console.log(query);
    });
});
```

**Client side function:**

```
function select()
            {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '/id',
                    success: function(data) {
                        var ceva = data;
                        console.log('#ceva');


                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a POST request rather than a GET request. Doing so will allow you to send data along with the request that you can then use in your query on the server side and send the response back to your client. Like so:

**Client Side**

```
function select() {

     var id = $('#My-ID-Input').val();

     $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/id',
        data : {
             id : id
        },
        success: function(data) {
             var id = data.id;
             $('#My-ID-Input').val(id);
        },
        error: function(err) {
             console.log(err);
        }

    });
}
```

**Server Side**

```
app.post('/id', function(req, res) {

    var data = req.body;
    var id = data.id;

    var query = "SELECT * FROM Control WHERE id=" + id;
    connection.query(query, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result);
    });

});
```

**GOTCHA!**

> You need to make sure that you have the `express` `bodyparser`
>   middleware implemented into your server to ensure that the data sent
>   as the body of the post request is then parsed into an object literal
>   on the server side. In your server module/file, you'll need to include the following code, and ensure that you've `npm install body-parser`:
>
> `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');`
>
> `app.use( bodyParser.json() );`

Comment: Yes, sure I have them. But what about the rest of the thing? the most annoying thing is how to selected based on the id entered in a textbox, and how to fill the textboxes with values selected. That's what I don't get.

Comment: You're using JQuery already, so you would just take the `data` response from the server and then update the value of any given input using JQuery. I've edited my response above to illustrate.

Comment: Ok. Got that. The only problem left is that you wrote the query to select only the column named id. But what I tried to do is to select all columns WHERE id = value from a text box. So. I don't understand how to send the value from client-side to server-side and use it to make the query right. I tried the query as: `request.param.id`, but it works only with what's after /, in the browser link. Hope you got my idea. Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's just an issue of updating your SQL query, as I've illustrated above. It has no bearing on how the data is passed between the client and server.

Comment: Ok. I got it, and the idea. I'll give it a try to see how it works in the morning. Thanks a lot for now . You're great !

Comment: What if I already have an app.post() that does some other post operation? How will I manage two different operations in a single post?